# Highjack or prevent UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to find a way to prevent or highjack `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. When a user selects a row in the tableview I want first throw an alertview saying "Data will be removed from CD if you do this." "We will be syncing the data to the server should you continue".

The user clicks yes continue. I want to prevent the new cell from being selected until the syncing completes. Should the syncing fail I want to pop an alert telling the user it failed and then stop `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from firing, thus preventing the new cell they touched from being selected.

Should the sync be successful I then want `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to be called.

Would the best way be to highjack `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement the delegate method

`-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and return `nil` for the relevant indexPath

This will stop the relevant cell being selected.

From the docs for `UITableViewDelegate`

> Return Value An index-path object that confirms or alters the selected
>   row. Return an NSIndexPath object other than indexPath if you want
>   another cell to be selected. Return nil if you don't want the row
>   selected.

Comment: That prevents it, but then how do I continue with the selection. I assume just manually call didSelectRowAtIndexPath with the index they selected (which I would hold onto from the willSelectRow..)?

Comment: If you want the cell to be visually selected you will have to keep a pointer to it and call [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableView *roomTable = tableView;
Rooms *room = [roomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Switching rooms will remove data for current thing. Need to download %@ room", room.name];
[UIActionSheet actionSheetWithTitle:message 
                            message:@"Message" 
             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" 
                            buttons:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]
                         showInView:self.view 
                          onDismiss:^(int buttonIndex)
 {
     NSLog(@"User selected to change the room");
     [roomTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
 }
                           onCancel:^
 {
     NSLog(@"Change Room Cancelled");
 }];

return nil;   
}
```